# Numerical error

Tags: natural-numbers, calculator

My brother told me that when he did this operation in the calculator: "the 2^33 root of one natural number", he obtains exactly 1.
 He asked me why (because I am a math student) but I don't know the answer. Do you?

Comment: was the natural number $1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, sorry, I must have used the word "a" natural number.

Comment: Roundoff error.  The answer is so close to $1$ that the calculator displays it as $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz I thought so, but I didn't know how to demonstrate it. Thank you for your answer 

Comment: $(1+x)^{1/2^{33}}\approx1+x/2^{33}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I should think about that. Thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), for $r\in(0,1]$ and $x>0$, $1\le(1+x)^r\le1+rx$.

Therefore, letting $n=1+x$, $1\le n^r\le 1+r(n-1)$.

With $r=2^{-33}$ and $n$ a number that is in the range to be fully displayed on the calculator ,

this forces $n^r$ to be so close to $1$ that, as [saulspatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz) commented, it displays as $1$.